# LateError was thrown building HomePage(dirty, state: _HomePageState#5847d): LateInitializationError: Field 'imgCamera' has not been initialized

Tags: flutter

[Error: Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following dependencies
don't support null safety:

- package:camera
- package:splashscreen

For solutions, see https://dart.dev/go/unsound-null-safety

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1035
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 55s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjUCq.png)I am getting the error:
The following LateError was thrown building HomePage(dirty, state: _HomePageState#5847d):
LateInitializationError: Field 'imgCamera' has not been initialized.
when I am trying to run the app on my android device .
my code is as follows:
homepage.dart

```
  import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:tflite/tflite.dart';
    import 'main.dart';
    //import 'package:splashscreen/splashscreen.dart';
    
    class HomePage extends StatefulWidget{
      @override
     _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
    }
    
    class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage>
    {
      bool isWorking = false;
      String result="";
      late CameraController cameraController;
      late CameraImage imgCamera;
    
     loadModel() async
     {
       await Tflite.loadModel(
           model:"assets/mobilenet_v1_1.0_224.tflite",
           labels:"assets/mobilenet_v1_1.0_224.txt",
       );
     }
    //this is for camera controller
      initCamera()
      {
        cameraController = CameraController(cameras[0], ResolutionPreset.medium);
        cameraController.initialize().then((value)
            {
              if(!mounted)
              {
                return;
              }
              setState(() {
                cameraController.startImageStream((imageFromStream) =>
                {
                  if(!isWorking)
                    {
                      isWorking = true,
                      imgCamera = imageFromStream,
                      runModelOnStreamFrames(),
    
                    }
                });
              });
            });
      }
     
this code is for runmodelonstream
      runModelOnStreamFrames() async
      {
        if(imgCamera != null)
          {
            var recognitions = await Tflite.runModelOnFrame(
              bytesList:  imgCamera.planes.map((plane)
              {
                return plane.bytes;
              }).toList(),
    
              imageHeight: imgCamera.height,
              imageWidth: imgCamera.width,
              imageMean: 127.5,
              imageStd: 127.5,
              rotation: 90,
              numResults: 2,
              threshold: 0.1,
              asynch:true,
    
            );
            result="";
            recognitions!.forEach((response)
            {
              result += response["label"] + " " + (response["confidence"] as double).toStringAsFixed(2) + "\n\n";
            });
    
            setState(() {
              result;
            });
            isWorking = false;
          }
      }
    
      @override
      void initState() {
    
        super.initState();
        loadModel();
      }
    
      @override
      void dispose() async
      {
    
        super.dispose();
    
        await Tflite.close();
        cameraController.dispose();//cameraController?.dispose();
      }
    
      @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context)
      {
        return MaterialApp(
          home: SafeArea(
            child: Scaffold(
              body: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage("assets/jarvis.png")
    
                  ),
    
                ),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                   Stack(
                     children: [
                       Center(
                         child:Container(
                           color: Colors.black,
                           height: 320,
                           width: 360,
                           child: Image.asset("assets/camera.png"),
                         ),
                       ),
                       Center(
                         child: TextButton(
                           onPressed: ()
                           {
                             initCamera();
    
                           },
                           child: Container(
                             margin: EdgeInsets.only( top: 35),
                             height: 270,
                             width: 360,
                             child: imgCamera == null
                                 ? Container(
                               height: 270,
                               width:360,
                               child:Icon(Icons.photo_camera_front, color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,size: 40,),
                             )
                                 : AspectRatio(
                               aspectRatio:cameraController.value.aspectRatio,
                               child: CameraPreview(cameraController),
    
                             ),
    
                           ),
                         ),
                       ),
    
                     ],
                   ),
                 Center(
                   child: Container(
                     margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 55.0),
                     child: SingleChildScrollView(
                       child:Text(
                         result,
                         style:TextStyle(
                           backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
                           fontSize: 30.0,
                           color: Colors.white,
    
                         ),
                       textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                       )
                     )
    
                   )
                 )
    
                  ],
                ),
              ), //img to background
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

please give me a detailed solution for this error as i am new to flutter technology

Answer (score 2):

I see imgCamera is late and non-nullable yet you check if it is null. Your error is because you're accessing a value declared late but wasn't initialized before being accessed
If an object will be null, then you make it nullable by adding a '?' in front.
So to solve your issue,

Solution:
change

```dart
late CameraImage imgCamera
```

to

```dart
CameraImage? imgCamera;
```

CameraImage? says that imgCamera can be null or a CameraImage.

You would get have to use a null-aware '!' to confirm that at the point of use, imgCamera isn't null.

It would also help to read up on dart's sound null safety

Comment: I made the changes, but still the same error .

Comment: What's throwing the error? try doing same to camera controller